# Chrome data compression proxy and DWR

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, mobile, dwr

We are developing a web mobile application using DWR as Ajax framework and we are getting errors in Nexus 4 devices which have enabled the option **Reduce data usage** in the **Bandwidth Management** setting. The error displays an alert saying **Error 502: Bad gateway** and it happens when refreshing a page that calls a DWR method in the onload event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I am the lead on the Chrome data compression proxy.)

The problem is a bug in the DWR library which uses JavaScript comments to contain semantically-meaningful content. The Chrome data compression proxy removes JS comments, which it is allowed to do by the headers; the fix is for DWR to use "Cache-Control: no-transform" in the DWR response headers. I emailed the DWR dev list a while back to ask about this but never heard back. We are looking for a general purpose workaround but in the meantime there's no easy fix unless DWR is fixed to work through HTTP proxies.

Comment: Thanks! Using DWR like this: `Remote.method(data, {callback: function(response){ // do something }, headers: {'Cache-Control': 'no-transform' }})` solves the problem

Comment: Glad this worked for you. We have a hacky rule which tries to avoid manipulating JS files ending in .dwr on the expectation that this would catch most cases; is the URL you're using named differently?

Comment: All the DWR URL's we are using end in .dwr but even though the errors have been decreased there are some situations where the problem still arise. We will eventually removing DWR and trying with jQuery

Comment: Same issue with some very, very basic PHP files.  Adding "header('Cache-Control: no-transform')" OR removing all comments fixed the 502 error.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but I find this very arrogant to call it a bug in the DWR library. A web developer has a right to expect that the code served up will be the same code that is received by the client. To do otherwise is to break the promise implicit in being a data carrier. This is a very bad decision on the part of Google to mess with developers code.

Comment: I disagree; this is not compliant with the HTTP spec which allows proxies to transform content. Resources which should not be modified by proxies need to have a Cache-Control: no-transform header per the RFCs.